# how to set uvmap texture size

Tags: texturing, uv

In order to learn uvmap and texturing, I want to create a model of King quest game pc box model.
The uvmap edges proportions are perfect, but much of the texture area is not in used (for example, the upper left uv coordinate is far from the upper texture edge - y=0.84). This is because the texture is squared, where the uvmap is set for a non squared image. I want the texture to be in the same size like the image I want to use - 1850x1260 pixels, while the default is squared one and I even can't find what is its size.

[image]

Here the process I did:

(1) Arranging an image for being the texture:
[image]

(2) Scaling a cube with the same proportions:
[image]

(3) Apply scaling, so transform's scale values are again (1,1,1)

(4) Remove default uvmap

(5) Create new uvmap with correct form by:

- Creating a seam
- Selecting all faces
- Unwarp
- Rotate and move uvmap and snapping to the grid to place it as was shown here above

Answer (score 2):

While in the shader editor tab, create a new texture with your desired dimension, or simply import the texture you want to use. With the texture node selected, go to the uv editing tab. The uv window should scaled accordingly to your images size.

[image: Creating a new texture]

[image: Resized uv window]

Comment: Thanks. first, in the image you gave, the uvmap lost its proportions. It should keep proportion, and just be placed over a correct texture size. Second, I followed your suggestion , add a texture node and set it to the image, but when going back to the uvmap editor nothing was changed.